# How to show and operate a remote Linux desktop when SSH or any other remote service is unavailable?

Tags: linux, ssh, windows, remote-desktop, lte

The situation is as follows. On Monday, I need to showcase a program that needs the set-up development environment and hardware on my home system, at the university. The ISP are misbehaving and won't turn on the static IP service which is required to use SSH (no workarounds possible, checked with the tech support, SSH is going to work only via the static IP service) until we pay a visit to the office and sort some legal stuff out (read, give them a kick..). Obviously, that's past Monday.

*What I have at my disposal:*

- the home machine, an Intel desktop PC running Fedora 23 with the required development environment and libraries, as well as the hardware the program needs to run on
- a laptop that I also own, a Lenovo L440, that has Windows 7 64 bit installed, and a free VMware Player with a Fedora 23 installed in it (vanilla, none of the environment I need is present there or can be set up in a sane amount of time, and of course the machine doesn't have the required hardware)
- a 100 MBit cable connection provided by the ISP behind a linksys router that I can log in to and change the necessary settings; alos, the ISP allows me to turn NAT on or off in the account settings on their website when necessary

*What I need:*

- To come to the university, connect the laptop to the Net (will be done either over the University wi-fi or, which is more probable, via a 4G USB modem with a speed of 64Kb/s, though in the case that a higher speed is required, I can pay a certain amount and have unlimited speed and bandwidth unlocked instantly)
- Then log into my home machine
- Be able to show the Fedora desktop (X.org, not just a getty login) and send mouse and keyboard input to it; well, just work on it remotely, you see

  SSH or anything the depends on a static IP isn't possible. What are my other options if any?

Comment: SSH does not depend on a static IP - it just depends on a *known* IP. Get an account with e.g. dyndns. Or get an IPv6 tunnel with a static IP address, which doesn't involve your ISP at all.

Comment: Those things will take a few days to set up and I need to polish the program until tomorrow.. Any solution like TeamViewer or a similar "dumb  and Windows-based" technology maybe?

Comment: No need for a static IP. I have a dynamic IP at home and setup the services pointing to a dynamic DNS name given by a free service, FreeDNS https://freedns.afraid.org ; the point is the ISP might not have the automations or does not want to give static IPs to residential tiers and/or does not have senior people working over the weekend. Normally a static IP is a paid extra/part of the professional Internet packages.

Comment: Why doesnt Teamviewer satisfy your needs? It says *In general, TeamViewer will always work if surfing on the Internet is possible. Hence, no firewall configuration is required.*

Comment: Does it work when the server and the client run different OS (win and linux in my case)?

Comment: I've not used it but I think it works between any OS. They say [makes it simple to work in a cross-platform world](https://blog.teamviewer.com/teamviewer-your-solution-to-a-cross-platform-life/)

Comment: @JennyD the tech support told me that "unless we use a static IP, it won't be possible to use SSH" and form my limited knowledge and testing, I've come to the conclusion that they are blocking any external access unless a static up is being used.

Comment: So this is not a unix question, it's an "how to get around my ISP's rules" question. Sorry.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's not about Unix, it's about how to get around the ISP's firewall rules.

Comment: @JennyD It is a Linux question because it is about "how to run a remote connection from linux to linux when tehre is no ssh working", sorry.

Comment: @JennyD but maybe it's just me lacking the required network knowledge, and the limitations I've described above are technically not possible.

Comment: You say that they are blocking any external access. If they are, then what you are asking is for us to help you get around their firewall rules.

Comment: @JennyD that depends on how you look at it. Isn't this situation *just* possible in an abstract linux environment (that ssh or other tools that depend on external access aren't working)? And, they haven't told me *explicitly* that they block, it's a guess. Sigh, that's the customer support.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Over simple SSH, you will not see Fedora desktop.
2. If you want to operate on desktop, probably only reasonable solution is VNC.
3. Not having static IP is not a disaster. You might use reverse port forwarding, if you have shell access to some other server with static IP (for example university).

There is also tool called [`autossh`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/autossh) which monitors this connection and restarts it, if it fails for some reason (restart of remote machine) to increase reliability.

In the bullet-points:

1. On your desktop, set up password-less connection to the server and start ssh:

   ```
   ssh -NTf -R 22:localhost:22022 public-ip
   ```
2. When you are at university, you can `ssh` to the same `public-ip` and then:

   ```
   ssh -p 22022 localhost
   ```

   will take you to your desktop.

You can forward the VNC ports similar way.

Few notes:

- Make sure your connection from desktop does not die

  - `autossh` to restore failed connections
  - `ServerAliveInterval`, `ServerAliveCountMax` options to send KeepAlive messages
  - make sure you desktop does not go to sleep
- Try things before presentation :) You should be able to verify functionality from home

Comment: "3" from teh first three points is impossible, I can't use or check stuff at the University. "Known IP" is impossible because it's the same thing as the static IP, no external connection seems to be possible unless we buy a static IP.

Comment: You might have access to some university server.

Comment: No, surely not in my case, and no time to set it up.

Comment: So I'm looking for something like teamviewer or so, that doesn't need a special IP. Is it possible?

Comment: This is common Linux practice. Teamviewer has to work in similar way, but it is using their static IPs from someone else. But I never used that. If you want "dumb and Windows-based", ask teamviewer question, probably on SuperUser.

Comment: OK, I thought about SuperUser as well. For now, I guess I'll just record a video of the program working, since the options listed are totally out of my current knowledge. Thank you for the explanation, will study that later!

Comment: Yes, video is also good solution and it "JustWorks". If that is a option, I would go that way.

Comment: Also, I was planning to use X forwarding with ssh, is that going to work once I have the ssh + static IP set up?

Comment: It should. But note that you will be able to run apps, but not to view your desktop and graphical environment, as pointed out in point "1".

Comment: it depends on what the OP wants to do really. If it is just running a graphical app, he can install a X server in Windows, and run it over SSH... http://www.straightrunning.com/XmingNotes/  ssh or XWindow do not need a "special" IP or a static one, as long as you know the IP address (risky), or have some service that points you to it (see my comment on the question). I been doing ssh and VPN to a dynamic IP for ages to connect remotely to  home without a static IP to an adress Iamnotellingyou.freedns.org

Comment: I mean, Jakuje, that's a great detailed answer, much appreciated! Though I lack the basic net knowledge to just go and implement it in an hour, obviously.